# Hive 0.13.0 - Where is the hive-hwi-.war file?

Tags: hive

I have installed Hive 0.13.0 which is the current stable release but when I want to start the hive web interface I experience the unexpected possibility to only see my root dir in the web under HIVEHOST:9999/hwi.

Looking for the hive-hwi-.war as it is mentioned in the documentation I found out that there is absolutely no war file in the lib directory.

Might it be a build error? Funny thing is that there is a hive-hwi-.jar which contains the same classes as the war should except the JSPs. So I guess the maven build is messed up.

Answer (score 4):

There is no hive-hwi-0.13.0.war file in hive-0.13

Just download hive-0.12 tar.gz from apache website

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-0.12.0/hive-0.12.0-bin.tar.gz

tar -zxvf hive-0.12.0-bin.tar.gz
```

Now copy hive-0.12.0-bin/lib/hive-hwi-0.12.0.war to /usr/lib/hive/lib/ and restart hive hwi as

```
hive --service hwi
```

Cheers:) It works

Now if you face issue related to ant and JAVA_HOME then please refer
[Ant build not working: unable to find a javac compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930181/ant-build-not-working-unable-to-find-a-javac-compiler/24334707#24334707)

It took my 5-6 hours but working smoothly now :)

Comment: One additional step that was needed was to copy jasper-compiler-jdt.jar to $HIVE_HOME/lib as suggested in : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5132

Answer (score 3):

This way is very long but it works for me,

First of all, you setup maven, and download source codes of hive. Then, you can run thefollowing codes in HIVE_HOME or untar file,

and edit your hadoop version in pom.xml
edit `<hadoop-20S.version>1.2.1</hadoop-20S.version>` for hadoop1
edit `<hadoop-23.version>2.3.0</hadoop-23.version>` for hadoop2

and run this code,

```
mvn install -pl hwi -am -P hadoop-1 -DskipTests
```

pl = compile mvn sub project

am = compile depends project

P = run selected profile you will chance other profile name, such as hadoop-2

and run this code for war file

```
mvn install -pl hwi -P hadoop-1 -DskipTests war:war
```

And if everything goes well, you will see BUILD SUCCESS

there will be hive-hwi war file in HIVE_HOME/hwi/target/